# How to assign a value for Slope of Different percent?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, slope

I have slope percent varying form 0 to 25 percent.  Now I want to give a value for each slope percent. For example, if my slope percent is 2 % , I want to assign a value of 10.  As a matter of fact, if it is a vector shapefile, then I can easily add a column for assigning those values in the attribute table. But since it is a raster image, I don't know how to assign those values for every slope percent.
Please tell me how to do it ??!

Comment: It would help if you can explain what you've done in a bit more detail. Also try translating laksh to a number range (its not common in use outside the Indian subcontinent). Please click edit below the question and give us a question that is about as long as you'd like the answer to be.

Answer (score 1):

Reclass...  You will have to take what I assume is continuous slope data and determine categories and then run a reclassification tool to assign the slope ranges new values.  I believe you would need to have spatial analyst to do this in ArcMap.  I'm not sure about some of the other products.